# -regex: No such file or directory

Tags: python, regex, subprocess

I tested a command to look for odt files in the current directory,
`find . -regex "*\.odt" -type f -maxdepth 1`
The command works well on the terminal. When I tried using python subprocess as such

```
subprocess.run(["find" , dirPath, " -regex", '".*\.odt"', "-type", "f", "-maxdepth", "1" ])
```

Where dirPath is the path to the directory I want to search in.

The result, however, shows me the list of files in the directory and returns the error

```
find:  -regex: No such file or directory
find: ".*level2\.odt": No such file or directory
```

Comment: remove the space before the `-` in `" -regex"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the space before the `-` in `" -regex"`.

Try this: 
`subprocess.run(["find" , dirPath, "-regex", '".*\.odt"', "-type", "f", "-maxdepth", "1" ])`

Comment: Your example still includes the space